# How to target specific clicked component and set the state for the specific component with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a dropdown component, which I use several times on a page.
Now this dropdown contains a number of options and the user has the possibility to select multiple options.

However, the page refreshes after choosing an option, which closes the dropdown.
The user then has to open the dropdown again to choose a 2nd option.

Now I want to make sure that the clicked dropdown remains open after choosing an option or refreshing the page.

The dropdown is displayed based on the `this.show` value.
If I set this directly to true in `mounted()`, all dropdowns are shown. I just want the dropdown that was already open to open after reloading the page.

Dropdown component:

```
<template>
  <div
    v-on-click-outside="collapse"
    class="dropdown"
    :class="{ expanded: show, collapsed: !show}"
  >
    <div
      class="dropdown__info"
      @click="onClick()"
    >
      <span>
        {{ getFilterTitle() }}
      </span>
    </div>
    <transition name="expand">
      <div
        v-if="show"
        class="dropdown__options"
      >
        <template v-for="(option, m) in filteredOptions">
          <template v-else>
            <div
              :key="option.value"
              :class="{
                selected: isSelected(option)
              }"
              :show="m < 10"
              class="dropdown__options__item"
              :title="option.title"
              @click="onSelect(option)"
            >
                {{ option.label }}
            </div>
          </template>
        </template>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

Functions:

```
data() {
    return {
        show: false
    };
},
methods: {
    onClick() {
        if (this.show) {
         this.collapse();
        } else {
         this.expand();
        }
    },
    expand() {
        this.show = true;
    },
    collapse() {
        if (!this.show) {
         return;
        }
        this.show = false;
    },
    onSelect(option) {
        const selectedIndex = this.selectedList.findIndex(
        (selectedOption) => option.value === selectedOption.value,
        );

        const clonedSelectedList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedList));

        if (selectedIndex > -1) {
         clonedSelectedList.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
        } else {
         clonedSelectedList.push(option);
        }

        this.selectedList = [...clonedSelectedList];

        this.onChange({
         title: this.title,
         name: this.name,
         value: this.selectedList,
        });
    }
}
```

How can I make sure to keep the dropdown open/shown after selecting an option, so that the user can select multiple options without opening the dropdown again?

Comment: Add `.stop` event modifier here `@click.stop="onSelect(option)"`, then add some flag to url params to hide/show the dropdown on page load

Comment: @VasileRadeanu what do you mean with flag to url params? can you show an example?

Comment: `www.site.com/page?dopen=1` based on `dopen` flag you can hide/open the dropdown on `mounted`. It's the same logic as `show` variable from `data`

Comment: but how does that know which dropdown needs to be open? and how can I add that in my code?

Answer (score 1):

If it's strictly necessary to keep dropdown state on page reload and if you have multiple dropdowns, then use `localStorage`. There you can store the id of opened dropdown and his selected options.

You can store in `JSON` format, below is parsed version

```js
[
  {
    id: "html_el_id",
    selected: [ 
      "option1", 
      "option2" 
    ]
  }
]
```

You have to decide how to generate `id` for dropdown, then sync state from `localStorage` with component `state` based on `id`.

Comment: this is not clear enough for me, can you show an example of how it works? @Vasile Radeanu